# HTML::FormHandler Form really slow

Tags: performance, perl, forms, catalyst

I am using [HTML::FormHandler](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::FormHandler) for a web app I'm creating. The forms work fine, the only issue is that just loading the form can cause the page 2-3 seconds to load. I know HTML::FormHandler uses [Moose](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose), and this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162390/is-moose-really-this-slow) has lead me to believe that Moose is the culprit. My web app is not using [catalyst](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst), so there isn't just the initial cost of loading the form and moose; it loads again every time a page is loaded. Is there anyway to reasonably use HTML::FormHandler in a non-catalyst web app? Or should I just give up and look for another form module? Thanks!

Comment: For a quick profile try `perl -d:DProf -MHTML::FormHandler -e0; dprofpp`

Comment: Using Moose based modules in non-persistend environments is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sort of issue that FastCGI was first introduced to solve: fundamentally a thin wrapper around a CGI program that makes it a persistent process.

[CGI::Fast](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI%3a%3aFast) is as good a place to start as any. If you're already using CGI.pm you should find the conversion pretty straightforward - certainly easier than converting the entire shebang to Catalyst or some other framework.